# extracting vectors from an array using logical indexing

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have the following numpy arrays:
a truth table of (nx1), and a matrix of (nxk) where n is 5 and k is 2 in this example.

```
btable = np.array([[True],[False],[False],[True],[True]])
bb=np.array([[1.842,4.607],[5.659,4.799],[6.352,3.290],[2.904,4.612],[3.231,4.939]])
```

I would like to extract the vectors in bb according the indexing values in btable.

I tried `choicebb=bb[btable==True]` which gets me the result

```
[ 1.84207953  2.90401653  3.23197916]
```

`choicebb=bb[btable]` gets me the same results as well.

What I want instead is

[[1.842,4.607]

[2.904,4.612]

[3.231,4.939]]

I also tried

```
choicebb=bb[btable==True,:]
```

but then I would get

> ---> 13 choicebb=bb[btable==True,:]
>
> 14 print(choicebb)
>
> IndexError: too many indices for array

This can be easily done in matlab with `choicebb=bb(btable,:);`

Comment: `btable` has to be `np.array([True,False,False,True,True])`.

Comment: I am generating it using a command like `matches=(idx==i)`, where idx is a kx1 array, and i is my matching criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the `1D` version of the mask with `np.ravel()` or slice out the first column with `[:,0]` and use it for logical indexing into the data array, like so -

```
bb[btable.ravel()]
bb[btable[:,0]]
```

Note that `bb[btable.ravel()]` is essentially - `bb[btable.ravel(),:]`. In NumPy, we could skip mentioning the trailing axes if all elements are to be selected, that's why it simplified to `bb[btable.ravel()]`.

**Explanataion :** To index into a single axis and such that it select all elements along the rest of the axes, we need to feed in a 1D array (boolean or integer array) along that axis and use `:` along the leftover axes. In our case, we are indexing into the first axis to select rows, so we need to feed in a boolean array along that axis and `:` along the rest of axes.

When we are feeding the `2D` version of the mask, it indexes along those corresponding multiple axes. So, when we feed in `(N,1)` shaped boolean array, we are selecting correct rows, but also only selecting the first column elements, which is not the intended output.

Comment: Thank you, this works! Could I get an explanation on the logic behind the need to get the 1D version of the mask since it is already a nx1 array?

Comment: @user2118915 See if the added comments make sense.

Comment: I get it now. Thanks!